# Making QGIS GUI responsive while adding multiple layers in Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, gui, ppygis

I have a tool button that add many layers from python code (WFS, PostgreSQL, ...), about 50 layers (30s to load) in QGIS.

During the process the application seem to be crashed *"not responding"*. I've tried to add layers with a `QgsTask` class but it crashes too because i have to be able to access to `QgsProject` instance. In the documentation there is an avertissement about this, so i can't use a `QgsTask` object.

Is there an other solution to keep the GUI alive when I make a heavy work?

EDIT :

I have isolated the part of my code for adding layers

```
def _loadLayers(self,layers, grp) :
    for layer in layers:
        currentLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), layer['name'], layer['type'])
        ...
        if (currentLayer is not None) :
           currentLayer.triggerRepaint()
           qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(currentLayer.id())
           QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(currentLayer, False)
           node = grp.addLayer(currentLayer)

conf  = Configuration.getOptions() # Json file with layers definition
if (conf is not None) :
   if ("groups" in conf) :
      ltr = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
      for child in conf['groups'] : 
          if ("groups" in child) : 
              self._loadGroup(child, ltr)
          elif ("layers" in child) :
              if (ltr.findGroup(child['name']) is None) :
                 grp = ltr.addGroup(child['name'])
                 self._loadLayers(child['layers'], grp)
```

Comment: How long did you wait for it? How big are the layers?

Comment: Can you show us the code to add the layers, it's hard to guess without it. Obfuscate the server name, username an password for your own protection.

Comment: @bugmenot123 i wait approximately 30sec

Comment: Please wait much longer for QGIS to unfreeze, if it does not come back after 15 minutes, start testing with only half the layers and iterate from there.

Comment: @bugmenot123 The problem is not the duration to wait. It works but when you have user that are not GIS specialist, the GUI that freeze is not really a good thing.... ! I display a message to inform user that is loading but i would like too the GUI stay alive (like if i use a QgsTask!)